# I'm learning how to solve Bernoulli differential equations and I'm stuck with one problem.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

This me preparing for university by doing some calculus. I was trying to solve this equation and got a different answer than Wolfram Alpha has. (General solution)

$\frac{dy}{dx} + 2xy = -xy^4$

I got $y^3 = 1 + \frac{e^{-3x^2}}{c}$ and Wolfram Alpha has $y = \frac{\sqrt[3]{-2}e^{2c_1}}{\sqrt[3]{e^{3x^2}-e^{6c_1}}}$.

Could you also point out where I made the mistake in my working out?

$\frac{dy}{dx} + 2xy = -xy^4$ assume $y\neq 0$.

$y^{-4}y' + 2xy^{-3} = -x$ let $z = y^{-3}$.

$\frac{dz}{dx} = -3y^{-4}\frac{dy}{dx}$ substitute $y^{-4}y'$ for $-\frac{1}{3}\frac{dz}{dx}$. Also, I will use the short hand $z'$ for $\frac{dx}{dx}$.

$-\frac{1}{3}z'+2xz=-x$

$z'-6xz=3x$ multiply this by the integrating factor $e^{\int{-6x}dx} = e^{-3x^2}$.

$e^{-3x^2}z'-6xe^{-3x^2}z=3e^{-3x^2}x$.

So, now I do the derivative of the integrating factor multiplied by $z$ to get $3e^{-3x^2}x$.

$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-3x^2}z) = -6e^{-3x^2}x$ Could someone also explain to me why the $z$ changes to an $x$ here? I know it's supposed to happen but don't understand why.

$-\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-3x^2}z) = 3e^{-3x^2}x$

$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-3x^2}z) = -6e^{-3x^2}x$

$e^{-3x^2}z = \int{-6e^{-3x^2}x}dx$

Let $u = -3x^2$ therefore $\frac{du}{dx} = -6x \to dx = -\frac{1}{6x}du$.

$e^{-3x^2}z = \int{e^{u}}du$

$e^{-3x^2}z = e^{-3x^2} + C$ where assuming $C$ is a general non-zero integration constant.

$z = 1 + \frac{C}{e^{-3x^2}}$

Hence, I got the answer $y^3 = 1 + \frac{e^{-3x^2}}{C}$

Sorry for the long question.

Comment: I'm not sure that $\frac{1}{y^3} = 1+\frac{c}{e^{-3x^2}}=\frac{c+e^{-3x^2}}{e^{-3x^2}} \implies y^3 = 1+\frac{e^{-3x^2}}{c}$. I believe it should be $\frac{e^{-3x^2}}{c+e^{-3x^2}}$ No? (ie simple algebra mistake at the end)

Comment: So, $y^3 = \frac{e^{-3x^2}}{c+e^{-3x^2}}$ it do look closer to the Wolfram Alpha result. But, how would that make the constant $C$ be in exponential? @KitterCatter

Comment: @Wojciech the constant is arbitrary, so you can redefine it however you please. You can change $C\mapsto \frac {C'}2$ or $C\mapsto e^{C''}$ for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is missing a factor of $-\frac12$*. With the factor in, it is $e^{-3x^2}z = -\frac12e^{-3x^2} + \frac C2$. Then: $$z=\frac C2e^{3x^2}-\frac12=y^{-3}\\y=\frac1{\sqrt[3]{\frac C2e^{3x^2}-\frac12}}=\frac{\sqrt[3]2}{\sqrt[3]{Ce^{3x^2}-1}}$$Now let $C=e^{-6c_1}$ and multiply the numerator and denominator by $\frac1{\sqrt[3]C}$. This gives $$y=\frac{\sqrt[3]2e^{2c_1}}{\sqrt[3]{e^{3x^2}-e^{6c_1}}}$$

So your solution is actually equivalent to the one given by WA. Yours is just given in terms of $y^3$, while theirs is in terms of $y$.

---

*
In your working you had the line $$e^{-3x^2}z'-6xe^{-3x^2}z=3e^{-3x^2}x$$ Then from here, you can notice that the LHS is exactly what you get if you differentiate $e^{-3x^2}z$ with respect to $x$, using the product rule. So the next line in your equation should be $$\frac d{dx}\left(e^{-3x^2}z\right)=3e^{-3x^2}x$$But in your solution, you put $-6e^{-3x^2}$ on the RHS. This is where you're missing the extra factor of $\frac12$.

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot more sense now. Thank you.